# Прием платежей через Z-payment

Tags: платежи, php

В обшем столкнулся с такой проблемой, что с сервера z-payment после оплаты не могу получить некторые данные, а точнее могу получить только номер счета. И форма для отправки post-запроса правильная

```
Сумма к оплате - {$currency} {$setup.currency_symbol}<br/><br/>
<form method="post" action="https://z-payment.com/merchant.php">
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PREREQUEST" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" value="ид магазина"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_NO" value="номер счета"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CLIENT_MAIL" value="ящик пользователя"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" value="Оплата заказа # {$row.id} через Z-Payment"/>
<input type="submit" value="Перейти к оплате" />
</form>
```

В success url данные получаю таким образом -

```
echo $_REQUEST['LMI_PAYMENT_NO']; - могу получить только это значение
echo $_REQUEST['LMI_PAYEE_PURSE'];
echo $_REQUEST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'];
```

Что я делаю не правильно? Платеж кстати на сервере z-payment проходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дня доброго. Вам нужно получать данные не на suc.url, а на result.url, т.к. согласно документации на страницу успешной оплаты передаются далеко не все параметры.

Comment: Это мне уже служба поддержки Интеркассы сказала) И ту платежку тоже подключал). А в z-payment об этом не удосужились мне сказать.